# Is there any way to get back a skipped mission?

Tags: fruit-ninja

I accidentally skipped a mission in Fruit Ninja and I really want to play it. I'm playing the version from the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.
However, there are few missions that are chosen randomly, so you will probably get that in the future.